# Where to put variable to increase by 1 in def loop?

Tags: python, selenium

I have this section of code:

```
if storagetypecheck1 == "Virtual":
        def storagecheck():
            d = 1
            dforid = str(1-d)
            while d <= int(numcount): 
                storageidprefix = "specimen" + "[" + dforid + "]"
                driver.find_element_by_id(storageidprefix + ".storageContainerForSpecimen").click()
                pag.press('a')
                pag.press('enter')
                time.sleep(1)
                d = d + 1
                storagecheck()
        storagecheck()
```

When the storage type of a webform is set to virtual, it will run and change the type to auto in the textboxes.

The problem is that it has to do so with multiple textboxes which follow the format `specimen[x].storageContainerForSpecimen`.

However, when I run this code, it just loops over and over without changing the value of `d` to `2`, `3`, etc.

I tried having `d = 1` above the `if` statement, but then it says for line `dforid = str(1-d)` that `d` is not defined.

Where should I put the `d = 1` expression so that it is able to be recognized by the `storagecheck()` loop while also being able to increase by `1` every loop?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: You _are_ incrementing `d` each time through the loop. But you're also recursively calling the whole function again each time through the loop, and the new function starts with its own `d = 1`, and it recursively calls itself, and the new function starts with its own `d = 1`, and it recursively… I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, and why you're recursively calling yourself in the first place. If you can explain that, maybe we can explain how to fix it. And if there _is_ no reason to do it, the solution may be as simple as just not doing that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`storagecheck()` calls itself recursively. Each time it calls itself, the line `d = 1` is being executed, so the value of d is being reset. You need to place `d` *outside* of the function definition for `d` to continue incrementing, like so:

```
if storagetypecheck1 == "Virtual":
        d = 1
        def storagecheck():
            global d
            dforid = str(1-d)
            while d <= int(numcount): 
                storageidprefix = "specimen" + "[" + dforid + "]"
                driver.find_element_by_id(storageidprefix + ".storageContainerForSpecimen").click()
                pag.press('a')
                pag.press('enter')
                time.sleep(1)
                d = d + 1
                storagecheck()
        storagecheck()
```

We use the keyword `global` to introduce the variable d into the namespace of the function.